# How to make multiple async parallel fetch calls in angular and not wait for response

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, async-await, observable

I am trying to make parallel fetch/ http.get requests but i am not able to do that asynchronously (around 400 http get calls).
My browser freezes for the time when these requests are being made.
So i want to make the call async so as to not wait for the function to finish

I have tried using async but wasn't able to make it async

```
async cacheNext(){
      console.log("Caching Images")
      this.cacheImages(imagearray)
      console.log("Cached Images")
    }
  }

async cacheImages(imagearray){
    imagearray.forEach(img => {
      fetch(img)
    });
  }


OR 

async cacheImages(imagearray){
    imagearray.forEach(img => {
      this.http.get(img).toPromise()
    });
  }
```

I expect that cacheImages function runs but the cacheNext finishes

Comment: If you are making 400 get requests you have made some terrible design decisions somewhere and need to rearchitect your app.

Answer (score 1):

As others have commented, if you are making 400 http calls, you likely have a design / architecture problem.

That aside, to make multiple, parallel http calls, and get a single callback with all of the results, I suggest using rxjs and forkJoin.

If you are doing Angular development, it's probably in your best interests to learn and get comfortable with rxjs, as much of the framework is built on it. Converting everything to Promises just seems to me to be extra, unnecessary work.

Rxjs excels at handling situations involving multiple async calls and other complex async issues. Its my experience that these complex situations are much more difficult to handle with promises.